# Getting Stored Procedure Information from .Net

Tags: c#, .net, sql, vb.net

I am trying to get some data relevant to a stored procedure (or function) back from a database using .Net. 
The first thing I need to be able to do, is get the stored proc from the database and turn it into string format.
The information I need is: The return set of columns, tables used within the SP, Stored Procedures called from the SP. The only way of doing this at the moment that I can think of, is though parsing the text and looking for keyword matches. Is there a better way of doing this?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're aware that the returned tables may be dependant on the inputs to the function, so there won't always be a single output for a given stored procedure, but...

To get a list of stored procedures you can call `sp_help`. You can then get the source of the stored procedure using `sp_helptext` (with `@objname` being the name of the stored procedure).

To find the referenced tables, columns, et al, you'd be wanting to parse the SQL script - you could do this yourself, or there are more established projects such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) that may simplify matters for you.

Comment: Thanks @Rowland, sp_heltext looks very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the SPROC as text, you can use a SQL Parser.

There are several for .NET- see the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76083/parsing-sql-in-net) SO question (Parsing SQL in .NET).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you can also try the sp_depends stored procedure

```
EXEC sp_depends @objname = N'sproc_name' ;
```